# reshape a data set based on one variable

Tags: r, reshape

I have a dataset like below:

```
Prefix  Ric Mrkt_segmt  Exchange
22  122N    E   NYM
22  222N    P   NYM
22  22N C   NYM
23  123L    E   NYM
23  223L    P   NYM
23  23L P   NYM
23  23L C   NYM
26  126L    E   NYM
26  226L    P   NYM
26  26L C   NYM
```

I want to reshape this data so it can look like this:

```
  prefix exchange ric_root1  mrkt_segmt1 ric_root2 mrkt_segmt2  ric_root3 mrkt3
   22       NYM      122N       E           222N      P              22N     C
   23       NYM      123L       E           223L      P
```

and combination of exchange_prefix and exchange are the unique ids

how can I do this in R?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Edit

With your updated data, change the code to something like the following. The concept is ***exactly*** the same:

In base R:

```
mydf$time <- with(mydf, ave(rep(1, nrow(mydf)), 
                            Prefix, Exchange, FUN = seq_along))
reshape(mydf, direction = "wide", 
        idvar=c("Prefix", "Exchange"), 
        timevar="time")
```

With "reshape2" after adding the "time" variable as above:

```
library(reshape2)
dfL <- melt(mydf, id.vars=c("Prefix", "Exchange", "time"))
dcast(dfL, Prefix + Exchange ~ variable + time)
```

---

#### Original answer

Add a "time" variable, and you're good to go:

```
mydf$times <- ave(mydf$ID, mydf$ID, FUN = seq_along)
reshape(mydf, idvar="ID", timevar="times", direction = "wide")
#   ID Var1.1 Var2.1 Var1.2 Var2.2
# 1  1      A      X      B      Y
# 3  2      C      X      D      Y
# 5  3      E      X      F      Y
```

---

Alternatively, after adding the "times" variable as we did above, you can use the "reshape2" package to further `melt` your data and then reshape it:

```
dfL <- melt(mydf, id.vars=c("ID", "times"))
dcast(dfL, ID ~ variable + times)
#   ID Var1_1 Var1_2 Var2_1 Var2_2
# 1  1      A      B      X      Y
# 2  2      C      D      X      Y
# 3  3      E      F      X      Y
```

Comment: when i add variable 'time', i receive below error- --   Error in `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, i, value = integer(0)) : 
  replacement has length zero

Comment: @Lawrence, without a reproducible example in your question, I won't be able to help you. This solution works with what you've shown so far.

Comment: how can i attach a csv file to this thread so that I can show you how the data look like/.

Comment: @Lawrence, can you please edit that into your original question. Also, it is better to use `dput(head(mydata))` or something along those lines since that will also retain information about the column types.